# how can i give permission to acess pages according to his role

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, roles

I'm developing a project that is based on institute system which have three main roles. In this project, `student, stuff and teacher` are in the main roles.

I would like to allow the user to access the pages according to the roles and some pages access without roles and permission.

**Responsibilities of teacher:**

1. create new student user id and password
2. post new notes
3. check student progress report
4. post new notice

**Responsibilities of stuff:**

1. fill the new inquiry form

**Responsibilities of student:**

1. check new notice
2. check latest notes
3. send holiday related application

I make gates for different user but i can't give roles and permission.
How can I implement this?
I did a lot of searching but i could not find any satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Laratrust package for role based permission, user based permission and team based permission as well.
https://laratrust.readthedocs.io/en/4.0/

Answer (score 0):

Use this spatie package for role permission
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission